# Accessing from Internet to a svn installed in a machine of a Wireless LAN

Tags: apache, svn, networking, lan

I would like to install a svn in a machine of a Wireless LAN (in my home: I haven´t bought any public IP), and access to it from internet. I would like to use Apache 2.2 + Subversion + SSL. In my wireless LAN, I have set a static IP for the machine with the SVN, to make it easier. My question is: when I install the Apache server, do I need a public network domain to serve my SVN, or is enough with my external IP (assigned to the router)? If I set it to the router, how should I redirect the traffic to my SVN server (that is in a machine with a private IP)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure your router to forward svn ports to your svn server. 
This includes port 80 and port 3690.
Then your svn will be accessible through your external IP.

You also can use [no-ip.com](http://no-ip.com) to get a permanent domain name that will point to your dynamic IP.

Comment: but if I redirect port 80, the other machines in the LAN cannot use Internet, can them?

Comment: There is a inbound and outbound traffic. When you are surfing the net, you are using others port 80. When you serve an application, you are using your own port 80. Setting up svn won't affect your ability to surf the net.

Comment: 1. 3690 is for svn:// access, useless for Apache-based 2. Incoming 80 on router is handled (and must be) by router's mini-http-server. YOU FAILED

Answer (score 1):

If your router have embedded http-server on 80 port, you can only redirect incoming port for https.

For external world your repo will be https://hostname-of-router/repo/path/, but served by internal host